# Can I set directory pattern when using TAILDIR source on Apache Flume?

Tags: flume

I use flume-1.8.0. 
On the document, it says that I cannot set the directory pattern.
(Regular expression (and not file system patterns) can be used for filename only.)
But I have to set the directory pattern to get log from other system which controlled by other team.
Is there some solution to set directory path like /dir/201801/0101.log, /dir/201802/0001.log, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this for the file groups with file patterns i.e use the Regex ASCII  pattern  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression for more details

```
a1.sources.r1.filegroups.f2 = /path/to/files/with/pattern/databundle_cnt_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.csv
```

In your case I will advise

```
a1.sources.r1.filegroups.f2 = /dir/[0-9]{6}/[0-9]{4}.log
```